# Как ускорить работу программы распознавания?

Tags: python, изображения, numpy

Имеется код, представленный в ссылке, как можно ускорить работу программы, так как аналогичная программа на Паскале с использование graphABC выполняется в 100 раз быстрее. Также не совсем понимаю, почему если вставлять в программу прикрепленные изображения (в ris st.bmp, в ris1 met.bmp), то программа зависает после обработки 5ого изображения рисунка met.bmp?
https://github.com/EgorNerushchenko/Recognition/blob/main/Programm.py

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]